# Stored Function in Oracle not Inserting Values into the desired table

Tags: sql, oracle, function

Here is my Code given below. I am trying to add 5 parameters which the function takes into the table Employee. But I am not successful in doing it and have tried a lot of things.

**Error**

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected ORA-06512: at "xxxxxxx.A1SF_ADDEMP", line 14
>   01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>   *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>              required by the format model.
>   *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Plus how do I test a Stored function that has a Insert/Update or Delete Statement in it?

**Execution Statement**

```
Select A1SF_ADDEMP('Adesh', '33', 'M', 8000, '26/03/1990')
From dual;
```

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function A1SF_ADDEMP
        (pEmpName In Varchar2,
        pTaxFileNo In Varchar2,
        pGender In Varchar2,
        pSalary In Number,
        pBirthdate In Varchar2
        ) Return Varchar2
        Is
          tEmpId Number(38,0);
          tBirthDate Date;

        BEGIN
              tEmpId := A1Seq_Emp.nextval;
              tBirthdate := to_date('pBirthdate','dd/mm/yyyy');

               Insert Into Employee(EmpId, EmpName, TaxFileNo, Gender, Salary, Birthdate)
                Values (tEmpId, pEmpName, pTaxFileNo, pGender, pSalary, tBirthdate);                 
                Commit;
                Return null;
        END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you cannot call a function with [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) in it in a select statement. You have to assign the output to a variable in a PL/SQL block, something like:

```
declare
  l_output number;
begin
  l_output := my_function(variable1, variable2);
end;
```

It's bad practice to do DML in a function; partly because it causes the errors you're coming across. You should use a procedure as detailed below. The other reason for this is that you're as always returning null there's no need to return anything at all!

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure ( <variables> ) is
begin

   insert into employees( <columns> )
   values ( <values > );

end;
```

The specific reason for your error is this line:
`tBirthdate := to_date('pBirthdate','dd/mm/yyyy');`

`pBirthdate` is already a string; by putting a `'` around it you're passing the string `'pBirthdate'` to the function `to_date` and Oracle can't convert this string into a day, month or year so it's failing.

You should write this as:
`tBirthdate := to_date(pBirthdate,'dd/mm/yyyy');`

You also don't need to specify `number(38,0)`, you can just write `number` instead.

It is possible to return a value from a procedure using the `out` keyword. If we assume that you want to return `empid` you could write is as something like this:

```
create or replace procedure A1SF_ADDEMP (
          pEmpName in varchar2
        , pTaxFileNo in varchar2
        , pGender in varchar2
        , pSalary in number
        , pBirthdate in varchar2
        , pEmpid out number
          ) return varchar2 is

begin

   pempid := A1Seq_Emp.nextval;

   Insert Into Employee(EmpId, EmpName, TaxFileNo, Gender, Salary, Birthdate)
   Values ( pEmpId, pEmpName, pTaxFileNo, pGender
          , pSalary, to_date(pBirthdate,'dd/mm/yyyy');     

end;
```

To just execute the procedure call it like this:

```
begin

    A1SF_ADDEMP( EmpName, TaxFileNo, Gender
               , Salary, Birthdate);
    commit;

end;
```

If you want to return the `empid` then you can call it like this:

```
declare

   l_empid number;

begin

   l_empid := A1SF_ADDEMP( EmpName, TaxFileNo, Gender
                         , Salary, Birthdate);
   commit;
end;
```

Notice how I've moved the `commit` to the highest level, this is to avoid committing stuff in every procedure when you might have more things you need to do.

Incidentally, if you're using Oracle 11g then there's no need to assign the value `A1Seq_Emp.nextval` to a variable. You can just insert it directly into the table in the `values` list. You, of course won't be able to return it, but you could return [`A1Seq_Emp.curval`](http://psoug.org/definition/CURRVAL.htm), as long as there's nothing else getting values from the sequence.

Comment: How will I be able to execute the above Function keeping in mind the DML statements do I have to use a Cursor or something?

Comment: @extinguisher33, as I explain in my answer you have to wrap it in a PL/SQL block; but I would covert it into a procedure instead.

Comment: Procedure thing I know cause I have studied SQL Server but I am very much interested in knowing how will I call, test this function on Sql developer and how will it be called from Visual Studio ;)

Comment: @extinguisher33, sorry I have no idea about visual studio; you'd have to ask another question for that, but if you want to execute this in SQL-Developer you should be able to just copy and paste what I've written.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **procedure** (instead of a function) if you are not returning any values.

If you look at the line mentioned in the error message you can spot your error:

```
tBirthdate := to_date('pBirthdate','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

You are passing the *string literal* 'pBirthdate' to the to_date() call. But you want to pass the parameter, so it should be

```
tBirthdate := to_date(pBirthdate,'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

(note the missing single quotes arount pBirthdate).

So as a procedure the whole thing would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE A1SF_ADDEMP
        (pEmpName In Varchar2,
        pTaxFileNo In Varchar2,
        pGender In Varchar2,
        pSalary In Number,
        pBirthdate In Varchar2
        )
IS 
BEGIN
   Insert Into Employee(EmpId, EmpName, TaxFileNo, Gender, Salary, Birthdate)
   Values (A1Seq_Emp.nextval, pEmpName, pTaxFileNo, pGender, pSalary, to_date(pBirthdate,'dd/mm/yyyy'));
   Commit;

END;
```

To run it:

```
execute A1SF_ADDEMP('Adesh', '33', 'M', 8000, '26/03/1990');
```

Comment: Cannot execute it like this.                                          Error starting at line 22 in command:
execute A1SF_ADDEMP('Adesh', '33', 'M', 8000, '26/03/1990')
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'A1SF_ADDEMP' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: When does this error occur? When you run the CREATE statement or when you run the EXECUTE statement? If it's the execute statement, then did you run the CREATE before in order to create a procedure instead of a function?

Comment: Only Procedures can be executed like this.

Comment: You are right, and I gave you the statement to create a procedure.

Comment: So Is there anyway I can execute this as a Function and then display the result?

Comment: Which result? Your initial function is not returning any result.

Comment: I mean How can I call this function from Visual Studio, There has to be some way of executing this and testing it.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. I don't do Visual Studio. You probably should create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you need to use procedure with out parameter where your out param is your returning param that contains your desirable value. This is I think best practice in this situation when you want to use DML in select statement.

Second way to do it but its not a good practice is to use one function like yours but before return a value you need to use if statement to check what is the value and if value is what you desire to call in this if statement PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION procedure which will do your DML independently of function calling to it. For more information about pragma transactions your can read here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm

Best Regards and hope I was helpful