# Why does this get-or-create function never seem to insert?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm writing a function for batch-importing data into our org-chart. It seems to work fine for retrieving entries that already exists, but when an entry does not already exist, and it's supposed to insert, commit, and return the result of a re-attempt (so as to get the auto-generated ID), it always returns `NULL`.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but what? Help appreciated.

**Note**: there's a before-insert trigger that fills in `DEPT_ID` if it's not specified. Works fine if the insert statement is executed by hand.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPTS 
(    
  "DEPT_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
  "HEADER_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
  "COMMENTS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
  "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_make_unit(
, in_cat VARCHAR2
, in_cmt VARCHAR2
, in_hdr VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  unit_id VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  unit_id := NULL;

  IF in_hdr IS NULL THEN
    SELECT dept_id
      INTO unit_id
      FROM depts unit
     WHERE unit.category = in_cat
       AND unit.comments = in_cmt
       AND unit.header_id IS NULL;
  ELSE
    SELECT dept_id
      INTO unit_id
      FROM depts unit
     WHERE unit.category = in_cat
       AND unit.comments = in_cmt
     AND unit.header_id = in_hdr;
  END IF;

  IF unit_id IS NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting!');
    INSERT INTO depts (
      header_id
    , comments
    , category
    ) VALUES (
      in_hdr
    , in_cmt
    , in_cat);
    COMMIT;
    unit_id := get_or_make_unit(in_cat, in_cmt, in_hdr);
    RETURN unit_id;
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not inserting!');
    RETURN unit_id;
  END IF;
END get_or_make_unit;
```

And the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HRD.DEPTS_BIR
BEFORE INSERT
ON HRD.DEPTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  JML NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT SEQ_DEPT_ID.NEXTVAL INTO JML FROM DUAL;
  :NEW.DEPT_ID:='D'||to_char(JML);
END DEPTS_BIR;
```

**Examples**

This works:

```
INSERT INTO depts (
      header_id
    , comments
    , category
    ) VALUES (
      'D532'
    , 'ACCOUNTING'
    , '2');
COMMIT;

SELECT get_or_make_unit('2', 'ACCOUNTING', 'D532') FROM DUAL;
=> 'D533'
```

This does not:

```
SELECT get_or_make_unit('2', 'NEW DEPT', 'D532') FROM DUAL;
=> NULL
```

Comment: Firstly, you have not created a "procedure",what you have created is a "function". These are two different object types in Oracle. A procedure is created using "CREATE PROCEDURE" syntax. For doing DML operations like you are doing, it is recommended that you create a procedure instead of function

Comment: Ah, I meant function, apologies. Brain fade! I'll probably change it to a ``PROCEDURE`` later on though, but it should work either way, right?

Comment: @michel-slm See one more update in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
INSERT INTO depts (
      header_id
    , comments
    , category
    ) VALUES (
      in_hdr
    , in_cmt
    , in_cat);
COMMIT;
unit_id := get_or_make_unit(in_cat, in_cmt, in_hdr);
```

use `RETURNING INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO depts (
      header_id
    , comments
    , category
    ) VALUES (
      in_hdr
    , in_cmt
    , in_cat) RETURNING dept_id INTO unit_id;
COMMIT;
```

I think recursive call in not the best approach, but if you are strict of using it, then please post definition of mentioned before-insert trigger.

**UPDATE:** You cannot call functions containing DML operations from SQL statement. Please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851992/2899629) for details. Example of correct call:

```
DECLARE
 unit_id varchar2(32);
BEGIN
 unit_id := get_or_make_unit('2', 'NEW DEPT', 'D532');
 dbms_output.put_line(unit_id);
END;
```

**UPDATE2:** Also you need to catch `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception that is raised when you call your function with not existent combination. Below is example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_or_make_unit(in_cat VARCHAR2,
                                            in_cmt VARCHAR2,
                                            in_hdr VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  unit_id VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  unit_id := NULL;
  IF in_hdr IS NULL THEN
    SELECT dept_id
      INTO unit_id
      FROM depts unit
     WHERE unit.category = in_cat
       AND unit.comments = in_cmt
       AND unit.header_id IS NULL;
  ELSE
    SELECT dept_id
      INTO unit_id
      FROM depts unit
     WHERE unit.category = in_cat
       AND unit.comments = in_cmt
       AND unit.header_id = in_hdr;
  END IF;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not inserting!');
  RETURN unit_id;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting!');
    INSERT INTO depts
      (header_id, comments, category)
    VALUES
      (in_hdr, in_cmt, in_cat)
    returning dept_id into unit_id;
    COMMIT;
    RETURN unit_id;
END get_or_make_unit;
```

Comment: Tried that and it's still returning NULL. Any idea?

Comment: Precede `NEW` with a colon in your trigger `:NEW.DEPT_ID:='D'||to_char(JML);`.

Comment: Tried that, it's not it. (plus running insert manually works with exactly the same invocation). Bizarre, this...

Comment: @michel-slm How do you call the function? Update your question with an example, please.

Comment: I've added an example (first showing a working combination of manually inserting and then querying with the function; second of querying for a non-existing entry, which should first perform a similar insert)

Comment: Thanks. assigning the result of the function call still does not work (in fact, I tried that already - looping through a temporary table containing the data to be inserted, assigning it to a variable that I then display for debugging purposes).

I get an exception when trying to assign the result to a VARCHAR2 variable: ``ORA-01403: no data found``

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Didn't realize that ``SELECT ... INTO`` could also throw "no data found".

Answer (score 0):

Your call to get_or_make_unit appears to be missing the first parameter.

Comment: The actual version had an extra parameter that's superfluous for highlighting the problem, I forgot to remove it when tidying up the code. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO depts (
      header_id
    , comments
    , category
    ) VALUES (
      in_hdr
    , in_cmt
    , in_cat);
```

This code is not inserting anything into dept_id of depts table. Thats the reason you are getting null

Comment: There's a before-insert trigger that does that (and does, if I call the insert statement by hand). I'll clarify the question, thanks.

Comment: @michel-slm You should add trigger definition to your question too to make your problem reproduceable.